# how to get certain items from database

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have items in a database with timestamp in milliseconds

I want to get the following items out of it:

last item of each month available in the items in the db

what would my query look like to achieve this ?

Comment: What kind of database is it?

Comment: Can you show some queries you're using/tried please? It will help us answer your question.

Comment: select * from mytable where ? i don't know what to write here, this is why i am asking, i need the latest item from each month, say i have 100 items in the database spread from january to december, the timestamps are in milliseconds, i want the latest item in each month

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you want, this is the gist of it. Add columns to the select as needed.

```
"SELECT STRFTIME('%m', time) AS month, max(time) FROM test GROUP BY month"
```

Self contained python script demonstrating:

```
from datetime import date
import sqlite3
import random


with open("./test", "w") as f:
    pass

conn = sqlite3.connect("test")
cursor = conn.cursor()

table_sql = "CREATE TABLE test (time TIMESTAMP)"
cursor.execute(table_sql)
conn.commit()

insert_sql = "INSERT INTO test VALUES(?)"
for x in range(100):
    start_date = date.today().replace(day=1, month=1).toordinal()
    end_date = date.today().toordinal()
    random_day = date.fromordinal(random.randint(start_date, end_date))
    cursor.execute(insert_sql, (str(random_day),))
conn.commit()


query = "SELECT STRFTIME('%m', time) AS month, MAX(time) FROM test GROUP BY month"
cursor.execute(query)
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Credit to: [Python select random date in current year](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4759223/python-select-random-date-in-current-year) for the random date selection technique.

Comment: `strftime` does not handle millisecond timestamps.